# Return values only (no keys/associative array) in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

### Situation

I have the following code to get all data as an array:

```
Data::select('id', 'text')->get()->toArray();
```

This will return the data in the following format:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "id" => "1"
    "text" => "Stack"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "id" => "2"
    "text" => "Overflow"
  ]
]
```

But I want only the values as a regular array (no keys/associative array) so the array is not converted to an object when I convert it to JSON:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:2 [
    0 => "1"
    1 => "Stack"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    0 => "2"
    1 => "Overflow"
  ]
]
```

### Inadequate solutions

I know I can convert this with a loop and use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php), but the former is not a one liner while the second works only for one level and not for arrays of arrays.

Also I'm looking for a way to "configure" Eloquent/Query Builder, and not a method to convert the once returned results.

### Questions

Is there a setting or a way I can do this **with Eloquent/Query Builder**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Just tell PDO to work this way:

```
DB::connection()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
Data::select('id', 'text')->get()->toArray();
DB::connection()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ;);
```

Don't forget to set back the default value or whatever was your previous setting. Also you will need to use these facades:

```
use DB;
use PDO;
```

### In details (behind the scenes)

This is controlled via the underlying PDO itself, that can by controlled via [`fetch_style`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php). The constant we need is this one:

> PDO::FETCH_NUM: returns an array indexed by column number as returned in your result set, starting at column 0

Now we just have to pass this in a Laravel way. This constant is passed to PDO in the `Illuminate/Database/Connection.php` file in the `select()` function's last line with a help of a getter:

```
public function select($query, $bindings = [], $useReadPdo = true)
{
    return $this->run($query, $bindings, function ($me, $query, $bindings) use ($useReadPdo) {
        if ($me->pretending()) {
            return [];
        }

        // For select statements, we'll simply execute the query and return an array
        // of the database result set. Each element in the array will be a single
        // row from the database table, and will either be an array or objects.
        $statement = $this->getPdoForSelect($useReadPdo)->prepare($query);

        $statement->execute($me->prepareBindings($bindings));

        return $statement->fetchAll($me->getFetchMode());
    });
}
```

Off course there is a public setter too: `setFetchMode()`, so we just have to receive the connector and we can set it. According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#accessing-connections):

> When using multiple connections, you may access each connection via the `connection` method on the `DB` facade.

So we have everything to do this:

```
DB::connection()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Comment: No longer support, it is giving error:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::setFetchMode()

Answer (score 0):

Method:

```
DB::connection()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
Data::select('id', 'text')->get()->toArray();
DB::connection()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ;);
```

## Is no longer an option after laravel 5.4

Possible workaround is as https://github.com/awesomedeba10 suggested here:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17557#issuecomment-536879106

You could add .env variable with default value in config.

config/database.php:

```
fetch_mode => env('DB_FETCHMODE', 'FETCH_OBJ');
```

.env:

```
FETCH_MODE=FETCH_OBJ
```

Then in Illuminate/Database/Connection.php>prepared

add this:

```
$statement->setFetchMode($config['fetch_mode'] == "FETCH_OBJ" ? 5 : ($config['fetch_mode'] == "FETCH_NUM" ? 3 : 2));
```

insetad of:

```
$this->fetchMode
```

Then you can overwrite your config with:

```
config()->set('database.connections.mysql.fetch_mode', 'FETCH_NUM');
```

This keeps fetch mode globally default FETCH_OBJ, yet you can still switch to FETCH_NUM whenever you need.