# Laravel 5.3 - how do I set fetchmode in query builder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-query-builder

I'm working with legacy code.  The old report engine uses associative arrays, Laravel's query builder returns an array of objects.

I need to turn objects into arrays. I've tried using:

`\DB::connection('tars-test') //->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

but that gets me `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\PDO' not found`

It's been suggested to put `->all()` at the end of the query but that throws error `Call to a member function all() on array`

The most efficient way would be to set the fetchmode at runtime, for the legacy function and just for the legacy function. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'toArray' method:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-toarray

Comment: Doesn't work. The return from the query builder is an array (of objects), so calling toArray on it just throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

### Laravel 5.3 and lower

You went the right way but as you can see laravel is trying to find PDO in `App\Http\Controllers\PDO` which probably means you forgot to add `use Illuminate\Database\PDO;`

### Laravel 5.4 and up

Since laravel 5.4 this is not an option. But you still can set fetch mode globally: [Laravel 5.4 - How to set PDO Fetch Mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795215/laravel-5-4-how-to-set-pdo-fetch-mode)

Or if you still wish to change it just locally:

[Return values only (no keys/associative array) in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368913/return-values-only-no-keys-associative-array-in-laravel/67636756#67636756)