# Laravel 5.4 - How to set PDO Fetch Mode?

Tags: php, pdo, eloquent, laravel-5.4, internals

The ability to customize the fetch mode was removed from L5.4 and is defaulted to PDO::FETCH_OBJ.

The upgrade guide states that you can override this by using an event listener:

```
Event::listen(StatementPrepared::class, function ($event) {
    $event->statement->setFetchMode(...);
});
```

I can't for the life of me understand how to implement this:

1) Where should I place the code? Should I register it with the `EventServiceProvider`?
2) When does the `StatementPrepared` event fire? (I only need to change the Fetch Mode  for specific repository functions, not on a global scale).
3) Does the FetchMode revert itself automatically for subsequent queries?

Here's an example of my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories\Backend;

use DB;
use PDO;

class SystemRepository
{
    /**
     * Get the connection status variables.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getConnectionStatus()
    {
        DB::connection('backend')->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $result = DB::connection('backend')
            ->select(DB::raw("
                SHOW STATUS
                WHERE Variable_name = 'Max_used_connections'
                OR Variable_name = 'Max_used_connections_time'
                OR Variable_name = 'Threads_connected'
            "))
        ;

        DB::connection('backend')->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: PS: The code example was working perfectly on Laravel 5.3

Comment: Be are of implications listening to this and change the fetch mode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47637869/database-query-builder-sometimes-returns-array-instead-of-object-running-as-a-qu

Answer (score 8):

Go to: *app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php*

Add this to the top of the file:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Events\StatementPrepared;
```

In the *boot* method add:

```
Event::listen(StatementPrepared::class, function ($event) {
    $event->statement->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
});
```

Comment: Ah I just realized you did not want it on a global scale. This would do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbh=DB::getPdo();
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SHOW STATUS
            WHERE Variable_name = 'Max_used_connections'
            OR Variable_name = 'Max_used_connections_time'
            OR Variable_name = 'Threads_connected' ");
$sth->execute(); 
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
print_r($result);
```

Try this. worked for me. You require only DB trait(use DB;).

Comment: or simply `DB::connection()->getPdo()->query($sql)->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: @wp78de - that one liner is perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel < 5.4

Add default fetch mode in config/database.php

```
return [
    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
    ...
];
```

Comment: Per the docs, this works great for Laravel versions below 5.4. Anything equal to or above 5.4 needs to use Scott's recommendation https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Theres another option I find to by pass it
Add env

```
DB_FETCHMODE=FETCH_ASSOC
```

In config/database add for connections.mysql

```
'fetch_mode' => env('DB_FETCHMODE', 'FETCH_ASSOC'),
```

In illuminate/datbase/connection.php replace prepared function with

```
protected function prepared (PDOStatement $statement){ 
    $config = $this->config;
    $statement->setFetchMode($config['fetch_mode'] == "FETCH_OBJ" ? 5 : ($config['fetch_mode'] == "FETCH_NUM" ? 3 : 2)); 
    $this->event(new Events\StatementPrepared(
        $this, $statement ));
    return $statement; 
 }
```

This make default `FETCH_ASSOC` for your application

Then if you want to change it like before,
add

```
config(['database.connections.mysql.fetch_mode' => 'FETCH_OBJ']);
```

a replacement of

```
DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on changing the fetch mode back and wrote a helper function to convert collections back into arrays-of-arrays:

```php
/**
 * Converts any iterable to an array-of-arrays. Intended for use with Laravel's {@link \Illuminate\Support\Collection} type.
 * Provided for backwards-compatibility because FETCH_ASSOC is no longer available.
 * Avoid using this in new code to prevent overhead of conversion.
 *
 * @return array[][]
 */
public function collection2array(iterable $collection): array {
    $out = [];
    foreach($collection as $el) {
        $out[] = (array)$el;
    }
    return $out;
}
```

I wouldn't recommend using it all over the place because it probably reduces performance but to get past some errors I had, this was the easiest.