# setFetchMode is ignored

Tags: php, eloquent

I'm trying to initialize eloquent with `setFetchMode` as `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`.

I've tried everything possible but it doesn't work.

What I tried so far :

To add it using the `addConnection`

```
$capsule = new Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;

$capsule->addConnection([
    ...
    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
]);
```

Using `setFetchMode`

```
$capsule->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Using events :

```
$t = new Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
$t->listen(Illuminate\Database\Events\StatementPrepared::class, function ($event) {
    $event->statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
});
```

But none of these work. Any idea how to make `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` work?

PS : I'm aware the first two options do not work with the recent version of eloquent, but I had to give it a try nonethless. I'm open to suggestions tho on how to make the third option work. Normally, the third one should start by looking like this `Event::listen`, but I don't know where is that `Events` class is coming from. Also do I need some sort of event listener?

PPS : I'm not using Laravel, I'm using illuminate's eloquent with PHP using composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the `illuminate/events` package and use this:

```
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
use Illuminate\Database\Events\StatementPrepared;
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;

$capsule = new Manager;
$capsule->addConnection([...]);

$dispatcher = new Dispatcher(new Container);
$capsule->setEventDispatcher($dispatcher);

$dispatcher->listen(StatementPrepared::class, function ($event) {
    $event->statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
});
```

Comment: I'll be trying this and I'll get back to you, thanks!

Comment: does this answer really do something different to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44916109/1247113 ? I'm currently using the `DB` facade, so I have no idea what I would have to add instead of the `[...]` in `addConnection`...

Comment: @rob74 The other answer is for Laravel users, this one for standalone users of the database package.

Comment: I completely missed that this question only referst to Eloquent, not to Laravel as a whole, sorry for that!